# changejQuery UI autocomplete markup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery UI autocomplete widget and am looking into adding to the markup in order to fix a design problem.

I basically want the suggestion box to not have a top box-shadow and the only way to only clip the top shadow is to have a surrounding container with `padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px` and `overflow: hidden`.

I tried adding `<div class="container> ... </div>` around the list markup in the js code, but it adds the same class to both the div and ul.

Here's the code in jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js:

```
 * jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.14
 *
 * Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete
 *
 * Depends:
 *  jquery.ui.core.js
 *  jquery.ui.widget.js
 *  jquery.ui.position.js
 */
(function(d){var e=0;d.widget("ui.autocomplete",{options:{appendTo:"body",autoFocus:false,delay:300,minLength:1,position:{my:"left top",at:"left bottom",collision:"none"},source:null},pending:0,_create:function(){var a=this,b=this.element[0].ownerDocument,g;this.element.addClass("ui-autocomplete-input").attr("autocomplete","off").attr({role:"textbox","aria-autocomplete":"list","aria-haspopup":"true"}).bind("keydown.autocomplete",function(c){if(!(a.options.disabled||a.element.attr("readonly"))){g=
false;var f=d.ui.keyCode;switch(c.keyCode){case f.PAGE_UP:a._move("previousPage",c);break;case f.PAGE_DOWN:a._move("nextPage",c);break;case f.UP:a._move("previous",c);c.preventDefault();break;case f.DOWN:a._move("next",c);c.preventDefault();break;case f.ENTER:case f.NUMPAD_ENTER:if(a.menu.active){g=true;c.preventDefault()}case f.TAB:if(!a.menu.active)return;a.menu.select(c);break;case f.ESCAPE:a.element.val(a.term);a.close(c);break;default:clearTimeout(a.searching);a.searching=setTimeout(function(){if(a.term!=
a.element.val()){a.selectedItem=null;a.search(null,c)}},a.options.delay);break}}}).bind("keypress.autocomplete",function(c){if(g){g=false;c.preventDefault()}}).bind("focus.autocomplete",function(){if(!a.options.disabled){a.selectedItem=null;a.previous=a.element.val()}}).bind("blur.autocomplete",function(c){if(!a.options.disabled){clearTimeout(a.searching);a.closing=setTimeout(function(){a.close(c);a._change(c)},150)}});this._initSource();this.response=function(){return a._response.apply(a,arguments)};
this.menu=d("hi!<ul></ul>").addClass("ui-autocomplete").appendTo(d(this.options.appendTo||"body",b)[0]).mousedown(function(c){var f=a.menu.element[0];d(c.target).closest(".ui-menu-item").length||setTimeout(function(){d(document).one("mousedown",function(h){h.target!==a.element[0]&&h.target!==f&&!d.ui.contains(f,h.target)&&a.close()})},1);setTimeout(function(){clearTimeout(a.closing)},13)}).menu({focus:function(c,f){f=f.item.data("item.autocomplete");false!==a._trigger("focus",c,{item:f})&&/^key/.test(c.originalEvent.type)&&
a.element.val(f.value)},selected:function(c,f){var h=f.item.data("item.autocomplete"),i=a.previous;if(a.element[0]!==b.activeElement){a.element.focus();a.previous=i;setTimeout(function(){a.previous=i;a.selectedItem=h},1)}false!==a._trigger("select",c,{item:h})&&a.element.val(h.value);a.term=a.element.val();a.close(c);a.selectedItem=h},blur:function(){a.menu.element.is(":visible")&&a.element.val()!==a.term&&a.element.val(a.term)}}).zIndex(this.element.zIndex()+1).css({top:0,left:0}).hide().data("menu");
d.fn.bgiframe&&this.menu.element.bgiframe()},destroy:function(){this.element.removeClass("ui-autocomplete-input").removeAttr("autocomplete").removeAttr("role").removeAttr("aria-autocomplete").removeAttr("aria-haspopup");this.menu.element.remove();d.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this)},_setOption:function(a,b){d.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this,arguments);a==="source"&&this._initSource();if(a==="appendTo")this.menu.element.appendTo(d(b||"body",this.element[0].ownerDocument)[0]);a==="disabled"&&
b&&this.xhr&&this.xhr.abort()},_initSource:function(){var a=this,b,g;if(d.isArray(this.options.source)){b=this.options.source;this.source=function(c,f){f(d.ui.autocomplete.filter(b,c.term))}}else if(typeof this.options.source==="string"){g=this.options.source;this.source=function(c,f){a.xhr&&a.xhr.abort();a.xhr=d.ajax({url:g,data:c,dataType:"json",autocompleteRequest:++e,success:function(h){this.autocompleteRequest===e&&f(h)},error:function(){this.autocompleteRequest===e&&f([])}})}}else this.source=
this.options.source},search:function(a,b){a=a!=null?a:this.element.val();this.term=this.element.val();if(a.length<this.options.minLength)return this.close(b);clearTimeout(this.closing);if(this._trigger("search",b)!==false)return this._search(a)},_search:function(a){this.pending++;this.element.addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");this.source({term:a},this.response)},_response:function(a){if(!this.options.disabled&&a&&a.length){a=this._normalize(a);this._suggest(a);this._trigger("open")}else this.close();
this.pending--;this.pending||this.element.removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading")},close:function(a){clearTimeout(this.closing);if(this.menu.element.is(":visible")){this.menu.element.hide();this.menu.deactivate();this._trigger("close",a)}},_change:function(a){this.previous!==this.element.val()&&this._trigger("change",a,{item:this.selectedItem})},_normalize:function(a){if(a.length&&a[0].label&&a[0].value)return a;return d.map(a,function(b){if(typeof b==="string")return{label:b,value:b};return d.extend({label:b.label||
b.value,value:b.value||b.label},b)})},_suggest:function(a){var b=this.menu.element.empty().zIndex(this.element.zIndex()+1);this._renderMenu(b,a);this.menu.deactivate();this.menu.refresh();b.show();this._resizeMenu();b.position(d.extend({of:this.element},this.options.position));this.options.autoFocus&&this.menu.next(new d.Event("mouseover"))},_resizeMenu:function(){var a=this.menu.element;a.outerWidth(Math.max(a.width("").outerWidth(),this.element.outerWidth()))},_renderMenu:function(a,b){var g=this;
d.each(b,function(c,f){g._renderItem(a,f)})},_renderItem:function(a,b){return d("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete",b).append(d("<a></a>").text(b.label)).appendTo(a)},_move:function(a,b){if(this.menu.element.is(":visible"))if(this.menu.first()&&/^previous/.test(a)||this.menu.last()&&/^next/.test(a)){this.element.val(this.term);this.menu.deactivate()}else this.menu[a](b);else this.search(null,b)},widget:function(){return this.menu.element}});d.extend(d.ui.autocomplete,{escapeRegex:function(a){return a.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g,
"\\$&")},filter:function(a,b){var g=new RegExp(d.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(b),"i");return d.grep(a,function(c){return g.test(c.label||c.value||c)})}})})(jQuery);
(function(d){d.widget("ui.menu",{_create:function(){var e=this;this.element.addClass("ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all").attr({role:"listbox","aria-activedescendant":"ui-active-menuitem"}).click(function(a){if(d(a.target).closest(".ui-menu-item a").length){a.preventDefault();e.select(a)}});this.refresh()},refresh:function(){var e=this;this.element.children("li:not(.ui-menu-item):has(a)").addClass("ui-menu-item").attr("role","menuitem").children("a").addClass("ui-corner-all").attr("tabindex",
-1).mouseenter(function(a){e.activate(a,d(this).parent())}).mouseleave(function(){e.deactivate()})},activate:function(e,a){this.deactivate();if(this.hasScroll()){var b=a.offset().top-this.element.offset().top,g=this.element.scrollTop(),c=this.element.height();if(b<0)this.element.scrollTop(g+b);else b>=c&&this.element.scrollTop(g+b-c+a.height())}this.active=a.eq(0).children("a").addClass("ui-state-hover").attr("id","ui-active-menuitem").end();this._trigger("focus",e,{item:a})},deactivate:function(){if(this.active){this.active.children("a").removeClass("ui-state-hover").removeAttr("id");
this._trigger("blur");this.active=null}},next:function(e){this.move("next",".ui-menu-item:first",e)},previous:function(e){this.move("prev",".ui-menu-item:last",e)},first:function(){return this.active&&!this.active.prevAll(".ui-menu-item").length},last:function(){return this.active&&!this.active.nextAll(".ui-menu-item").length},move:function(e,a,b){if(this.active){e=this.active[e+"All"](".ui-menu-item").eq(0);e.length?this.activate(b,e):this.activate(b,this.element.children(a))}else this.activate(b,
this.element.children(a))},nextPage:function(e){if(this.hasScroll())if(!this.active||this.last())this.activate(e,this.element.children(".ui-menu-item:first"));else{var a=this.active.offset().top,b=this.element.height(),g=this.element.children(".ui-menu-item").filter(function(){var c=d(this).offset().top-a-b+d(this).height();return c<10&&c>-10});g.length||(g=this.element.children(".ui-menu-item:last"));this.activate(e,g)}else this.activate(e,this.element.children(".ui-menu-item").filter(!this.active||
this.last()?":first":":last"))},previousPage:function(e){if(this.hasScroll())if(!this.active||this.first())this.activate(e,this.element.children(".ui-menu-item:last"));else{var a=this.active.offset().top,b=this.element.height();result=this.element.children(".ui-menu-item").filter(function(){var g=d(this).offset().top-a+b-d(this).height();return g<10&&g>-10});result.length||(result=this.element.children(".ui-menu-item:first"));this.activate(e,result)}else this.activate(e,this.element.children(".ui-menu-item").filter(!this.active||
this.first()?":last":":first"))},hasScroll:function(){return this.element.height()<this.element[d.fn.prop?"prop":"attr"]("scrollHeight")},select:function(e){this._trigger("selected",e,{item:this.active})}})})(jQuery);
```

Does anyone know how to add additional, independent html to the widget?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the div surrounding the list markup, assign the CSS values directly, as they will be added inline, instead of via a class. Inline CSS takes precedence over class rules.

for instance:

```
$(".list_item").wrap(
    $("<div>").css({padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px, overflow: hidden})
);
```

Not tested, but something like that should work.

Comment: Where would I add that? I've been trying to add the div in the  jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js file at `this.menu=d("<ul></ul>").addClass("ui-autocomplete")` .

Comment: It's easier to see in the non-minified file. You can change it there and then minify it again.  But why change the library?  You can just add that code snippet anywhere in your site's code and it'll modify the list after the fact.